# Where do I find things to do in Firefall?

Tags: firefall

After the first missions about the water I've sort of run out of things to do with my accord recon character. Are there more missions available somewhere? Ive heard about the staged content phenomenon where you can push back the melding but how do I actually do that?

Comment: Simon & Lewis from the yogscast did a few videos on this game. Link is down at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much in the game at the moment beyond the first mission and endless PvP, for the simple reason that it's still in beta.

The developers are slowly adding things to do, but at the moment it's fairly empty.

Answer (score 0):

do /gf or /givefun to have Aero or Oilspill tell you about events nearby that you can do.